# Make a Synchronous call in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have an input field which I want to validate.

I am using a custom validator to check the validity of that input field value.

In the custom validator, I am making a rest call to an endpoint with the input field value to check if the entered value is valid.

The issue is the httpClient get call works in an async way, by the time the validation results are returned from the rest API. The input field validators come out and validation does not work per expectation.

Is there a way to make http call synchronously.

my httpClient call code inside a custom validator:

labelNameValidators.ts:

```js
import {FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function labelNameValidators(control: FormControl) {

  if(control.value!=null) {
    this.labelService.checklabelNameFormat(control.value)
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {

        if (data === 'true') {
          console.log('success', data);
          return  {'labelMsg': { 'message' : data}};
        }
        else {
          console.log('failure', data);
          return  {'labelMsg': { 'message' : data}};
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
        return null;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Label.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LabelService {

private nameFormatCheckApi = environment.nameFormatCheckApi;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  checklabelNameFormat(name: string){
    return this.http.get(this.nameFormatCheckApi + '?name='+name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to make sync calls? You can make it work with async validators: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation

Comment: you can set a boolean value to true/false and then write a sperate method which will eventually return the boolean.

Comment: create a directive, update that directive once you get response from your endpoint and it will trigger your field.errors.directive thing which you will create. If you have some submit/save buttons mark a check with a boolean value at component which should only be true after getting any response from the endpoint and should change to false once you click save/submit or change field values.

Comment: Abhishek's suggestion is _a_ solution, but it's convoluted for no reason. Angular provides async validators (linked by Krishna) for precisely this use-case. That also keeps all the form validation logic _within the reactive form,_ which you almost always want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use async validators for your case.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      fieldExample: new FormControl(
        null, Validators.required, asyncValidator())
});
```

here you are a live demo using async validators with template-driven forms and reactive forms.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbdorarjxea